# One API that can transfer money to multiple payment gateway

Tags: java, payment-gateway

Is there any api that will take params such as users credit card number, expiration date, cvc, amount and send that money to a customize payment gateway account such as Paypal, BrainTree, Authorize.Net etc.

Comment: Are you talking about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460993/paypal-api-can-we-transfer-money-to-multiple-accounts-in-a-transaction

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

http://apievangelist.com/2014/02/26/payment-apis-that-i-am-watching/

Plenty of Payment Gateway you can check in above link and for youe specific requirement you can check in same link.

**Spreedly**

Spreedly is a cloud based `credit card vault that allows you to work with one or multiple payment gateways over time or simultaneously`. Dramatically reduce your PCI compliance scope, work with the world’s payment gateways and add on newer payment types like Dwolla and GoCardless.

Answer (score 0):

You must be carefull with systems (cloud platforms ) which stores Credit data. They must be clomplaint with [PCI DSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard).

Paypal Vault :  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-vault-overview/  . In this other [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086267/paypal-vault-storage-sending-credit-card-info-securely) u can get more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use paypal Adaptive payment gateway

[**Paypal**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)